# How can I write to Rails logger within my gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a gem which I wrote and I use it inside my rails application.

I want to write to rails logger from my gem but obviously the standard rails logger doesn't exist there.

What is the right way to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: What about `Rails.logger.debug`? Or `Rails.logger.info`, etc.?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While you should be able to use `Rails.logger` you might want to consider making the logger that your gem uses configurable, i.e. allow users to set `MyGem.logger` to whatever logger they want.

You can default it to something that just writes to stdout, in a rails app you can set `MyGem.logger = Rails.logger` in an initialiser. People who are using your gem outside of rails can do so too.

Answer (score 15):

As Frederick Cheung says, you should use a namespaced logger for your gem: `MyGem.logger`.

Then set it to the Rails logger in a Railtie so that your gem works nicely both inside and outside of Rails.

```
module MyGem
  class Railties < ::Rails::Railtie
    initializer 'Rails logger' do
      MyGem.logger = Rails.logger
    end
  end
end
```